# Automatic re-numbering of prioritized list VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of priorities in Excel, for example:

```
4, 
1,
3,
2
```

I want it to automatically update the priorities, if I enter a new name and assigns a priority. For example, if the new name has a priority of 2.

```
5,
1,
4,
3,
2
```

I have the following VBA code, which should do the job, but I can't get it to run.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngPriorityList As Range
    Dim lNewValue As Integer
    Dim myCell As Range

    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then 'Only run if the a number was entered

        Set rngPriorityList = Intersect(Target, Range("I3:I500")) 'the named range for the task list

        If Not Intersect(Target, rngPriorityList) Is Nothing Then 'Only run the following in the cell being updated was in the priority list range
            If Target.Value >= 1 Then
            For Each myCell In rngPriorityList.Cells 'Loop through the priority list range
                If myCell.Value = Target.Value _
                And myCell.Address <> Target.Address Then 'Finding cells with the same value, excluding the cell being changes
                    myCell.Value = myCell.Value + 1 'Increment the prioriry by 1
                End If
            Next myCell
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Using a table is out of the question?

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to achieve :(

Answer (score 0):

a possible correction

wrong setting of rngprioritylist (should be Range("I3:I500" i.o. intersect( ...))

wrong test of mycell.value (should be >= i.o. =)

events should be disabled during the adaptation of the priorities as modifying the priorities will trigger the worksheet_change event.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngPriorityList As Range
    Dim lNewValue As Integer
    Dim myCell As Range

    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then 'Only run if the a number was entered

        Set rngPriorityList = Range("I3:I500") 'the named range for the task list

        If Not Intersect(Target, rngPriorityList) Is Nothing Then 'Only run the following in the cell being updated was in the priority list range
            If Target.Value >= 1 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each myCell In rngPriorityList.Cells 'Loop through the priority list range
                If myCell.Value >= Target.Value _
                And myCell.Address <> Target.Address Then 'Finding cells with the same value, excluding the cell being changes
                    myCell.Value = myCell.Value + 1 'Increment the prioriry by 1
                End If
            Next myCell
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```